# iOS7 UITextView set NSLinkAttributeName attribute but can not click

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

[image]

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITextViewDelegate>


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"www.google.com"];
    NSDictionary *linkDic = @{ NSLinkAttributeName : [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] };
    [str setAttributes:linkDic range:[[str string] rangeOfString:@"www.google.com"]];
    _textView.attributedText = str;
}


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    NSLog(@"=============%@",URL);
    return YES;
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the following in IB > Utilities > Attributes Inspector. Notably the UITextView **cannot** be editable and have links enabled.

[image: UITextView Settings]

You can also do the same with code:

```
_textView.editable = NO;
_textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Comment: Thant's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: also necessary: textView.selectable needs to be YES otherwise this wont work

Comment: Thanks for that added gotcha @Wirsing ! Annoying that it means the user can also accidentally select the text...

Comment: Your welcome, this got me hung up, too. And yes, it definitely is annoying!